# Error in java comparator class while sorting the array?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

[image]

I am getting this error please tell how to correct it

Comment: Welcome to SO , please check up on Boxed vs primitive types. Integer vs int , Long vs long . That should get you started

Comment: Please do not add code as images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: please paste your code as problem description, not a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sort an array in ascending order by:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

If you need to sort the array in descending order you can use:

```
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Note: If you gonna use `Comparator` inside `Arrays.sort` you probably get :

> The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the
> arguments (int[], new Comparator(){})

Answer (score 0):

Never give images !!! always code !!!

Java comparator must return an int (as shown in signature)

(edited after comments)

```java
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2){
   return Math.abs(o2) - Math.abs(o1);
}
```

Comment: Only solves 3/4 of the error messages, the first one remains.

Comment: Yes ! Use Comparator<Integer>, primitive types can't be used as type parameters in java

Comment: "Java comparator must return an int" - and then your answer shows the use of `Integer`...

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're right, I edited my answer too quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

The return type of compare method is int and you are returning a boolean value.

Modify the code to return an int value.

Also, comparator class requires object datatype. Modify your array from int[] to Integer[]

```
Integer[] nums = new Integer[]{not, tak, twice};
    Arrays.sort(nums, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {
            return Math.abs(o1) - Math.abs(o2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only solves 3/4 of the error messages, the first one remains.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to first sort on the absolute values, and when equal on the signed value.

And then the `Arrays.sort` with a `Comparator` only is for Object derived classes, not the primitive type `int`. So you need an `Integer[]`

```
Integer[] nums = {not, tak, twice};
Arrays.sort(nums,
    Comparator.comparingInt(n -> Math.abs(n.intValue())
              .thenComparingInt(Integer::intValue));
```